# Button is always null even after window is loaded

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in javascript.
I am trying to click a play button which is in an embedded video player.

Here is the button code :

```
<button id="play" class="svg-button" tabindex="0" title="play" focusable="true"></button>
```

I opened the console and typed this in :

```
document.getElementById('play').click();
```

But I always get the same error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null`

The only time it works is when I right click the play button -> inspect element, then go back to the console and re-type `document.getElementById('play').click();`
Then the video launches normally and the button is no longer null.

I have no idea how to solve this problem, if anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: is the button in an iframe by chance?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes it is

Comment: there's your problem then - getElementById doesn't look in iframe documents

Comment: So why does it work after I click inspect element ? And is there any way to click the button then ?